# MSAccess: Formatting a Custom Ribbon Menu

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm stuck delivering an Access 2010 app to a bunch of Access 2007 users using Access Runtime.

I have constructed a custom menu ribbon that provides the necessary functions.  It is working as required, but formatting of the "Text Formatting" group looks a little funky:

[image: Custom Shortcut Menu]

The following is the XML I used for the Text Formatting Group:

```
<mso:group id="mso_c1.3AC2B47" label="Text Formatting" autoScale="true">
    <mso:control idQ="mso:Font" visible="true"/>
    <mso:control idQ="mso:FontSize" visible="true"/>
    <mso:control idQ="mso:AlignLeft" visible="true"/>
    <mso:control idQ="mso:AlignCenter" visible="true"/>
    <mso:control idQ="mso:AlignRight" visible="true"/>
</mso:group>
```

I'm looking to position Font and Size combo boxes side-by-side, and the 3 alignment icons below...

Any suggestions to try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting close.

I am able to group the 3 alignment buttons together, but cannot likewise group the font/size combos.  Maybe a little less funky. :)

[image: Try #2]

```
<mso:group id="mso_c1.3AC2B47" label="Text Formatting" autoScale="true">
    <mso:control idQ="mso:Font" visible="true"/>
    <mso:control idQ="mso:FontSize" visible="true"/>
    <mso:buttonGroup id="Align">
        <mso:control idQ="mso:AlignLeft" visible="true"/>
        <mso:control idQ="mso:AlignCenter" visible="true"/>
        <mso:control idQ="mso:AlignRight" visible="true"/>
    </mso:buttonGroup>
</mso:group>
```